# Efficient algorithm to compute the $n$th Fibonacci number

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, recurrence-relation

The $n$th Fibonacci number can be computed in linear time using the following recurrence:

```
def fib(n):
    i, j = 1, 1
    for k in {1...n-1}:
        i, j = j, i+j
    return i
```

The $n$th Fibonacci number can also be computed as $\left[\varphi^n / \sqrt{5}\right]$.  However, this has problems with rounding issues for even relatively small $n$.  There are probably [ways around this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7145/calculating-binets-formula-for-fibonacci-numbers-with-arbitrary-precision) but I'd rather not do that.

Is there an efficient (logarithmic in the value $n$ or better) algorithm to compute the $n$th Fibonacci number that does not rely on floating point arithmetic?  Assume that integer operations ($+$, $-$, $\times$, $/$) can be performed in constant time.

Comment: As a suggestion, the Wikipedia article on Fibonacci numbers has lots of methods.

Comment: cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661633/finding-out-nth-fibonacci-number-for-very-large-n/14661885#comment29320519_14661885 and links therein and around.

Comment: “Rounding issues” So how much precision do you need?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use matrix powering and the identity
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^n = \begin{bmatrix} F_{n+1} & F_n \\ F_n & F_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}.
$$
In your model of computation this is an $O(\log n)$ algorithm if you use repeated squaring to implement the powering.

Comment: It's a classic.

Comment: You can also use this identity to derive the recurrences $F_{2n-1} = F_n^2 + F_{n-1}^2$ and $F_{2n} = F_n^2 + 2F_{n-1}F_n$.

Answer (score 7):

You can read this mathematical article:
*A fast algorithm for computing large Fibonacci numbers* (Daisuke Takahashi):
[PDF](http://www.ii.uni.wroc.pl/%7Elorys/IPL/article75-6-1.pdf) .

More simple, I implemented several Fibonacci's algorithms in C++ (without and with GMP) and Python. Complete [sources](https://bitbucket.org/OPiMedia/severalgos/src/master/Fibonacci/) on Bitbucket. From the main page you can also follow links to:

- The C++ HTML online documentation.
- A little mathematical document:
  *Fibonacci numbers - several relations to implement good algorithms*

The most useful formulas are:

- $F_{2n} = F^2_{n + 1} - F^2_{n - 1} = 2 F_n F_{n - 1} + F^2_n$
- $F_{2n + 1} = F^2_{n + 1} + F^2_n$

Be careful on algorithm. You must not calculate the same value several times.
A simple recursive algorithm (in Python):

```
def fibonacci_pair(n):
    """Return (F_{n-1}, F_n)"""
    if n != 0:
        f_k_1, f_k = fibonacci_pair(n//2)  # F_{k-1},F_k with k = n/2
    
        return ((f_k**2 + f_k_1**2,
                 ((f_k*f_k_1)*2) + f_k**2) if n & 1 == 0  # even
                else (((f_k*f_k_1)*2) + f_k**2,
                      (f_k + f_k_1)**2 + f_k**2))
    else:
        return (1, 0)
```

Its complexity is logarithmic (if the basic operations are in constant time): $O(\log n)$.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.se]. Please could you add more information to your answer? At the moment, it's nothing more than two links, so your answer will become meaningless if those links die or the servers they're on are unavailable. Links to more information are fine but the links here are the only information. Also, please note that the question is very definitely about algorithms, not about C++ implementations. Implementations tend to obscure the algorithms behind language-specific details.

Comment: David, the first link is a link to a mathematical article. The title *A fast algorithm [...]* answers to the question "Is there an efficient (logarithmic in the value n or better) algorithm [...]?"

The second link is a link to my various implementations, in C++ **and** Python, and a little mathematical document with several formulas.

Comment: No, the *title* of the article, which is what your answer contains, answers nothing. The *text* of the article, which your answer contains almost none of, sounds like it probably does answer the question. But Stack Exchange is a question and answer site, not a link farm. (And, no, I'm not suggesting that you copy-paste the article into your answer. But a summary is needed.)

Comment: If you want a summary, write it!

Answer (score 1):

We should first note that Fibonacci numbers $(F_n)$ grow very fast with $n$ and cannot be represented in 64-bits for $n$ larger than 93. So a program for computing them for such $n$ needs to use additional mechanisms to operate on these large numbers. Now, considering only the count of (large-number) operations, the algorithm to sequentially compute them will require linear number of operations.

We can benefit from the below identity about Fibonacci numbers:

$ F_{2m} = 2F_mF_{m+1}−{F_m}^2$

$ F_{2m+1}={F_m}^2+ {F_{m+1}}^2 $

So, if we know $F_m$ and $F_{m+1}$, we can directly compute $F_{2m}$ and $F_{2m+1}$.

Consider the binary representation of $n$. Observe that starting with $x=1$, we can make $x=n$ by iteratively doubling and possibly adding 1 to $x$. This can be done by iterating over the bits of $n$, and checking if it is 0 or 1.

The idea is that, we can maintain $F_x$ in sync with $x$. In each such iteration, as we double $x$ and possibly add 1 to $x$, we can also compute the new value of $F_x$ using the earlier value of $F_x$ and $F_{x+1}$, with above equations.

Since the number of iterations will be logarithmic in $n$, the total (large-number) operations are also logarithmic in $n$.

For further details, please refer section "Improved Algorithm" of this [article](https://mathsanew.com/articles/calculating_fibonacci_numbers.pdf) (written by me).

Comment: (Cf [nth Fibonacci number in sublinear time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63014691/3789665).)

Answer (score 0):

Basic theory and code for computing linear recurrences with constant
coefficients in $O(\log_2 n)$ is available from http://www.jjj.de/.

Check the free book [Matters Computational](http://www.jjj.de/fxt/fxtpage.html#fxtbook) and the pari/gp code.

Comment: Better to summarize the ideas instead of just posting links.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to perform `q` queries asking `fib(n)` for multiple `n` values, you can use dynamic programming to solve it in O(`n + q`).

```
int dp[100];

int fib(int n){
    if(dp[n] != 0) return dp[n];
    dp[n] = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    return dp[n];
}
```

The idea is to store already processed values so if the recurrence call that value, if returns in O(1).